# Ambiguous column name error when ordering by id

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm getting this error when trying to order data received from a content provider by "ID":

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: ambiguous column name: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT anydo_tasks.due_date, anydo_tasks.title, anydo_categories.name AS category_name, anydo_tasks._id, anydo_tasks.status, anydo_tasks.priority FROM anydo_tasks INNER JOIN anydo_categories ON anydo_tasks.category = anydo_categories._id WHERE (status <> 0 AND parent_task_id IS NULL ) AND (status=?) ORDER BY _id ASC

The code i'm running is this:

```
String orderBy = TasksContract.TasksColumns.ID + " ASC";

mCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(TasksContract.TASKS_URI, null,TasksContract.TasksColumns.STATUS + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(TasksContract.STATUS_UNCHECKED) }, orderBy, null);
```

I've seen other questions here that state that this is probably because two tables use ID, but in my query I'm pretty sure I'm specifying the correct table. What's going on here?

Comment: Try changing `ORDER BY _id` to be the `_id` of the table that you want it ordered by. In other words, either `anydo_tasks._id` or `anydo_categories._id`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! Guess I need to brush up on using databases in Android.